# Not able to fetch User who is having Permission as part of CERTIFICATE as Securable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Purpose of the query is to fetch all permissions for Particular user with all the details.

Please find my query below :

```
 SELECT 'permUser1@master'                      AS dbUserName,
       dp.NAME COLLATE database_default        AS principal_name,
       dp.principal_id,
       dp.type_desc COLLATE database_default   AS principal_type_desc,
       grantor.NAME COLLATE database_default   AS grantor,
       class_desc = CASE p.class_desc
                      WHEN 'ASYMMETRIC_KEY' THEN 'ASYMMETRIC KEY'
                      WHEN 'SYMMETRIC_KEYS' THEN 'SYMMETRIC KEY'
                      ELSE p.class_desc
                    END,
       p.major_id,
       Object_schema_name(p.major_id)          fun_object_schema,
       Object_name(p.major_id, 1)              AS fun_object_name,
       (SELECT NAME COLLATE database_default
        FROM   [master].sys.server_principals
        WHERE  principal_id = p.major_id)      AS ser_object_name,
       (SELECT NAME COLLATE database_default
        FROM   [master].sys.database_principals
        WHERE  principal_id = p.major_id)      AS object_name,
       (SELECT NAME COLLATE database_default
        FROM   [master].sys.symmetric_keys
        WHERE  symmetric_key_id = p.major_id)  AS symmetric_key,
       (SELECT NAME COLLATE database_default
        FROM   [master].sys.asymmetric_keys
        WHERE  asymmetric_key_id = p.major_id) AS asymmetric_key,
       (SELECT NAME COLLATE database_default
        FROM   [master].sys.assemblies
        WHERE  assembly_id = p.major_id)       AS assembly_name,
       (SELECT CASE type_desc
                 WHEN 'SQL_USER' THEN 'USER'
                 WHEN 'CERTIFICATE_MAPPED_USER' THEN 'USER'
                 WHEN 'DATABASE_ROLE' THEN 'DATABASE ROLE'
                 WHEN 'ASYMMETRIC_KEY' THEN 'ASYMMETRIC KEY'
                 WHEN 'SYMMETRIC_KEYS' THEN 'SYMMETRIC KEY'
                 ELSE 'DATABASE'
               END
        FROM   [master].sys.database_principals
        WHERE  principal_id = p.major_id)      AS securable,
       p.permission_name,
       ao.type_desc                            AS object_desc,
       p.state_desc                            AS permission_state_desc,
       dp.sid
FROM   [master].sys.database_permissions p
       INNER JOIN [master].sys.database_principals dp
               ON p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
       LEFT JOIN [master].sys.database_principals grantor
              ON p.grantor_principal_id = grantor.principal_id
       INNER JOIN [master].sys.database_principals excludeAppRoles
               ON excludeAppRoles.principal_id = grantor.principal_id
                  AND excludeAppRoles.type_desc <> 'APPLICATION_ROLE'
       LEFT JOIN [master].sys.all_objects ao
              ON p.major_id = ao.object_id
WHERE  dp.principal_id = 40  AND class_desc = 'CERTIFICATE'
```

My output :

[image]

I was expecting to find this user in the above result:

[image]

When I debug I found that 104 value is not at all present in `database_principle` table. For this user wheres he is present with 6 value.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [master].sys.database_principals 
WHERE principal_id = 6;
```

[image]

Also value 101 is coming right from `server_principle` table but

How can I find user linking with 104 value ? I totally got stuck

Comment: `104` is the value in `major_id` which can join on a number of different tables, which you can tell from `type_desc` . The value coming from `sys.server_principals` is bogus and a complete red-herring in this case, you need to join on `sys.certificates` to get the certificate name

Comment: @Charlieface : Thanks I got the problem. seems like we don't support Certificate it self in query.  you comment "The value coming from sys.server_principals is bogus" clear the things. Thanks again